# MSAL Client flow Azure Function in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, azure, authorization, azure-ad-msal

Looking to use MSAL client flow to gain to authorize access to an Azure Function which I have configured to use Microsoft Authentication .

I've add the latest preview of the MSAL and can log in and gain access to the Graph API

```
 App.TokenRequest = await App.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(App.Scopes,App.UiParent)
 var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
 var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://{my site url}/.auth/login/microsoftaccount");  

request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new TokenContent { access_token= App.TokenRequest.AccessToken }));
 var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Any ideas would be helpful, when I navigate to the auth page in the browser I get the server side flow. but the above client request always yields a 401 error, the documentation is all over the place and I was trying to avoid using the Mobile App Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Client-managed authentication - Live SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#client-livesdk), we could find that you need to pass the following payload for logging:

```
{"authenticationToken":"{Live-SDK-session-authentication-token}"}
```

Then, I checked [LiveSDK](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK) and tried to retrieve the [LiveConnectSession.AuthenticationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.live.liveconnectsession.authenticationtoken.aspx) by calling `LiveLoginResult.Session.AuthenticationToken`, but it returns null.

Then, I checked the the server-flow authentication for Microsoft Account, and find it would use [Live SDK REST API - Signing users in with REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659750.aspx). I tried to simulate the authentication request via postman to verify this issue. Here is my test for retrieving the access token:

`https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={client-id}&redirect_uri={return-url}&response_type=code&scope=wl.basic+wl.offline_access+wl.signin`

[image]

As you could see, we could not retrieve the `authentication_token` as mentioned in the official document about [Get an access token and an authentication token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659750.aspx).

Then, I tried to use the `access_token` for logging as follows, and found it could work.

[image]

> Looking to use MSAL client flow to gain to authorize access to an Azure Function which I have configured to use Microsoft Authentication .

For MSAL, you could find it would send request against the following endpoint and both `{"authenticationToken":"App.TokenRequest.AccessToken"}` and `{"access_token":"App.TokenRequest.AccessToken"}` payload could not login successfully.

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

Per my test, since the Authentication / Authorization for Microsoft uses the different authentication endpoints, the token generated by each endpoints could not be applied to each other.

Based on my test, you could just create you app at [Microsoft Account Developer Center](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) and add authentication info for your azure function app. For your client, you could use [LiveSDK](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK) [deprecated] or [OneDrive SDK for CSharp](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp) for MSA logging and retrieve the `access_token` for logging with your azure function app. Here is my UWP client for logging with OneDrive SDK, you could refer to it:

```
var msAuth = new MsaAuthenticationProvider(
    "{app-Id}", //application id of your app
    "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", //the redirect url for your native application in your app
    new string[] { "wl.signin", "offline_access" });
await msAuth.AuthenticateUserAsync();
```

[image]

For `MsaAuthenticationProvider`, you could refer to [Authentication Adapter for the OneDrive SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-dotnet-msa-auth-adapter).

Comment: I'll give the onedrive sdk a go, but it looks like the heart of the issue is since MSAL is targeting the new end point, I cant use the easy authorization that I can set up on the App service in the portal.  Can I use both Work and Personal accounts in the OneDrive SDK ?

Comment: Per my test, for apps registered at [Microsoft Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/), it would work with Microsoft account. For apps registered at [Microsoft Azure Active Directory](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), it would support work or school users for your tenant. For more details, you could refer to [Authentication Adapter for the OneDrive SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-dotnet-msa-auth-adapter).

Comment: Per my understanding, MSAL could not work with Authentication / Authorization from Azure App Service for now.

Comment: Thank you for the insight that last bit of information wasnt clear from the documentation